# Bibliography missing from PDF (Sublime Text 2 and Miktex)

Tags: miktex, editors

I have installed latest Build of **Sublime Text 2** and **Portable version of MiKTeX**.

Now I want to set up Sublime Text 2 so that I can compile LATEX (.tex) documents to create PDF's.

I read the info from [LaTeX Plugin for Sublime Text 2](https://github.com/SublimeText/LaTeXTools)

> Finally, you must check the file LaTeX.sublime-build in the directory
>   in which you unzipped the LaTeXTools plugin to make sure that the
>   configuration reflects your preferred TeX distribution. Open the file
>   and scroll down to the section beginning with the keyword "windows".
>   You will see that there are two blocks of settings for the "cmd" and
>   "path" keywords; by default, the MikTeX one is active, and the TeXlive
>   one is commented out. If you use MikTeX, you don't need to change
>   anything: congratulations, you are done!

The LaTeX.sublime-build is missing from my installation. So I have created LaTeX.sublime-build file under 
`C:\Program Files\Sublime Text 2\Data\Packages\LaTeX` directory With following content

```
{
   "cmd": ["pdflatex", "$file"],
   "path": "D:\\UserData\\majeedk\\[2012] Latex\\miktex-portable\\miktex\\bin;$PATH",
   "file_regex": "^(...*?):([0-9]+): ([0-9]*)([^\\.]+)",
   "selector": "text.tex.latex"
}
```

Now The PDF gets created but bibliography is missing from the resulting PDF.
How can I enable it?

Comment: You need to run bibtex or biber, whichever you normally use.

Answer (score 3):

To compile the bibliography you have to adapt your build system as follows:

```
{
    “cmd”: ["pdflatex $file_base_name && 
             bibtex $file_base_name && 
             pdflatex $file_base_name && 
             pdflatex $file_base_name && 
             gnome-open $file_base_name.pdf"],
    “file_regex”: “^(…*?):([0-9]*):?([0-9]*)”,
    “selector”: “source.latex.tex”,
    “shell”: true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you installed [LaTeX-Tools](https://github.com/SublimeText/LaTeXTools) correctly, there should be a corresponding folder in the package directory which contains the build orders:

```
path\to\Sublime Text 2\Data\Packages\LaTeXTools
```

If you don't want to (re)install LaTeXTools and want to use your own build command instead, you should consider using [texify](http://docs.miktex.org/manual/texify.html) instead of `pdflatex`. `texify` will trigger the necessary multiple runs to create a proper TOC and will also invoke `bibtex` when it is required. Your `LaTeX.sublime-build` should contain the following lines:

```
{
"selector": "text.tex.latex",
"cmd": ["texify", "-b", "-p", "--tex-option=\"--synctex=1\"", "$file"],
"path": "D:\\UserData\\majeedk\\[2012] Latex\\miktex-portable\\miktex\\bin;$PATH",
"file_regex": "^((?:.:)?[^:\n\r]*):([0-9]+):?([0-9]+)?:? (.*)$"
}
```