# Sublime Text 2 and bibtex

Tags: bibtex, editors, latexmk

I'm using Sublime Text 2 (ST2) with LaTeXTools to build my .tex-documents. But the .bib-file is not found or doesn't build (I believe the last one). The LaTeX log reports undefined citations, and the entire bibliography is missing form the PDF. I have searched the web for a solution. Although a similar problem occurs in [Bibliography missing from PDF (Sublime Text 2 and Miktex)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/59457/bibliography-missing-from-pdf-sublime-text-2-and-miktex), I made a new LaTeX build command using the answer from elleestcrimi, but it doesn't work.

Somebody have an idea about what I can do? I call the .bib-file from the `\bibliography{ref.bib}` command and have the standard LaTeXTools build-file:

```
{
"cmd": ["latexmk", "-cd",
            "-e", "\\$pdflatex = 'pdflatex %O -interaction=nonstopmode -synctex=1 %S'",
            //"-silent",
            "-f", "-pdf"],
"path": "$PATH:/usr/texbin:/usr/local/bin",
"file_regex": "^(...*?):([0-9]+): ([0-9]*)([^\\.]+)"
},
```

Edit: As the latexmk documentation points out that bibtex will be run even if there is no .bib-file present, I haven't really considered the alternative to manually run bibtex. I would like bibtex to build anyhow.

Edit2: When I build my document from ST2 with LaTeXTools (see above), then the bibtex-command from github:

```
{
"cmd": ["bibtex", "$file_base_name"],
"path": "$PATH:/usr/texbin:/usr/local/bin",
"file_regex": "^(...*?):([0-9]+): ([0-9]*)([^\\.]+)",
"selector": "text.tex.latex"
}
```

and rebuild with LaTeXTools the bibliography is included and the sun is shining.

EDIT3: I'm now not able to reproduce the problem. It somehow seems to have solved itself. Typesetting with ST2 produces all the files it should, and the bibliography is included.

Comment: Have you actually run `bibtex` (i.e. `bibtex myfile.tex`)?

Comment: When `bibtex` is run on `myfile.tex`, it generates `myfile.bbl`. Is there a `.bbl` file in your directory?

Comment: @IanThompson Comment 1: See edit =) Comment 2: No. There are no `.bbl` file in my dir.

Comment: To narrow down the problem, try doing `bibtex myfile.tex` directly from the command line, then typesetting your document. What happens?

Comment: @IanThompson See edit2. Seems my bibtex runs fine when it is run solo. What I don't understand is why either my bibtex doesn't work with latexmk, or latexmk doesn't call bibtex.

Comment: @Holene Do you also see the problem if you invoke `latexmk` from the command line?

Comment: @JohnCollins No, when running latexmk from the command line, everything works fine. I have set `pdf_mode = 1` and `dvi_mode = 0`in the latexmk perl script, though.

Comment: @Holene Because you find `latexmk` works from the command line but not from within ST2, the problem is probably a difference between the environments in ST2 and at the command line.  If you could send me a copy of `latexmk`'s output with an explanation of exactly what you did, I could maybe debug the problem.  (It would help if you removed the `-silent` and `-f` options from your configured command line for `latexmk` in ST2. That would give more debugging information.)  Send me this off-line, to the e-mail given in `latexmk`'s documentation.

Comment: Thanks for the help guys, the problem has now somehow solved itself. Everything works fine.