# Biber Installation Corrupted?

Tags: biblatex, biber

I have come across an unusual problem and found no answers after due diligence. I am using Biblatex and Biber but my citations are undefined. Things have worked fine in the past and only changes in content were made. My usual debugging process did not solve the problem. Also, not even the MWE in the following link works (let alone other MWE's found elsewhere):

[Biblatex, Biber, and LaTeX: citations undefined](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/153647/biblatex-biber-and-latex-citations-undefined)

The MWE in the link above used to work fine. I used the debug process described at the bottom of the post in the link above. My .blg file shows nothing. The problem persists in both Sublime Text and TeXStudio, suggesting the problem is independent of editor. I think Biber may be corrupted, but not sure if that's possible or how it could happen. According to TeX Live Utility on Mac, "universal-darwin" and "x86_64-darwin" packages are both "Installed" for latexmk and biber.

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Terminal output:

```
INFO - This is Biber 1.8
INFO - Logfile is '/Users/andrewwong/Dropbox/researchUCI/Shirey/first.tex.blg'
data source /var/folders/9w/srfgxgpd6372qtp2dyr_x4r40000gn/T/par-   
616e64726577776f6e67/cache1ea1c894d061cba85b64a1b380f6c297de02c7c4//
inc/lib/Biber/LaTeX/recode_data.xml not found in .
```

The following is displayed in first.tex.blg:

```
[0] 554906f9.pm:318> INFO - This is Biber 1.8
[0] 554906f9.pm:321> INFO - Logfile is '/Users/Dropbox/researchUCI/Shirey/first.tex.blg'
```

Comment: Try running biber with your terminal `biber <nameOfYourExample>` (in your working directory of course).  
Is there any output?

Comment: Open a terminal, go into the documents direktory and run by hand `biber <filename>`. What's the output?

Comment: [Biblatex/biber fails with a strange error about missing recode\_data.xml file](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/140814)

Comment: delete this folder `/var/folders/9w/srfgxgpd6372qtp2dyr_x4r40000gn/T/par-   
616e64726577776f6e67/`  and run it again. It will take sone time, because `biber` will first extract itself the files.

Comment: I have problems with biber using stale caches on my MikTeX install on Win7. Have you tried deleting the given data source ('/var/folders/...')?

Comment: btw: You should run biber on your masterFileName **without** the extension

Comment: Thanks for the leads. Reading everything and will report back in a few minutes.

Comment: Thanks for everyone's help. I'm new, so it's hard sometimes to figure out the right question to ask. This question is indeed a duplicate. Deleting the /var folder fixed my problem. Thanks all.