# Calling Biber on TeXstudio

Tags: biblatex, texstudio

For the first time, I'm creating a document which really needs a long bibliography, i.e. requires the `biblatex` package or similar. I've read some questions and answers here, and I think I pretty much replicated a common structure of the `.tex` file. Here's what I have:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[brazil]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber,citestyle=authoryear,style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{bueno,
  title={Vísceras da memória: uma leitura da obra de Pedro Nava},
  author={Bueno, Antônio Sérgio},
  volume={15},
  year={1997},
  publisher={Editora Ufmg},
}
@article{castro,
  title={Além de Braverman, depois de Burawoy: vertentes analíticas na sociologia do trabalho},
  author={Castro, Nadya Araújo e Guimarães, Antônio Sérgio Alfredo},
  journal={Revista Brasileira de Ciências Sociais},
  volume={6},
  number={17},
  year={1991},
}
@book{souza,
  title={Multiculturalismo e racismo: uma comparação Brasil-Estados Unidos},
  author={Souza, Jessé e Sant'Anna, Alayde},
year={1997},
  publisher={Paralelo 15},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\section{Introdução}
Aqui vamos falar de algumas obras, nomeadamente \cite{bueno} e \cite{souza}. Talvez falemos também de \cite{castro}.

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

(I use TeXstudio 2.6.6 with pdfLaTeX.)

The `pdf` output shows the citation texts just like their labels, only on bold (e.g., my second citation prints as "**souza**"), and it lacks the bibliography. The log file gives me this:

```
LaTeX Warning: Citation 'bueno' on page 1 undefined on input line 39.
LaTeX Warning: Citation 'souza' on page 1 undefined on input line 39.
LaTeX Warning: Citation 'castro' on page 1 undefined on input line 39.
LaTeX Warning: Empty bibliography on input line 41.
```

I also get a very strange `! Paragraph ended before \DeclareBibliographyStrings was complete.`

I suspect there might be a problem with the configurations of TeXstudio, although I have read the accepted answer on [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/153647/biblatex-biber-and-latex-citations-undefined) and followed the steps therein.

So my (pretty dumb) question is: What am I doing wrong?

Comment: related: [Biblatex with Biber: Configuring my editor to avoid undefined citations](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/154754)

Comment: @Harish Yes, the answer regarding TeXstudio in those pages is exactly the same as the one I linked to, as their author recognises in a comment. My thing is: I _did_ follow those steps (as they were presented, at least), but I keep getting the same error/warning messages, and my output file is _still_ wrong!

Comment: OK, if you've set up Biber correctly and run it, you should have a `.blg` file: can you edit in the content? Presumably there is some error.

Comment: @DrewLara, just compiled your code with LuaLaTeX, and ran fine.