# Chicago Style with BibTeX

Tags: biblatex, bibtex, citing, miktex, chicago-style

I'm using [Zotero Better BibTeX](https://github.com/retorquere/zotero-better-bibtex/wiki) to automatically import the bibliography I need, but it uses BibLaTeX and BibTeX, and I am required to use Chicago style. I think

```
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=chicago-authordate,natbib=true]{biblatex}
```

would be perfect. However, I'm having trouble to convert to `biber`.

When I use `biber` as a backend, following [lockstep's advice](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/153647/biblatex-biber-and-latex-citations-undefined), i.e. LaTeX Biber LaTeX, I get no errors, but the in-text citations are the automated keys Zotero generates: `author_firsttitleword_date`. If I rerun LaTeX, I get a lot of "undefined control sequence \entry" and "\endentry", and the logfile is the following monster:

> ```
> ! Use of \sortlist doesn't match its definition.
> l.21   \sortlist{
>              nty}{nty}
> If you say, e.g., `\def\a1{...}', then you must always
> put `1' after `\a', since control sequence names are
> made up of letters only. The macro here has not been
> followed by the required stuff, so I'm ignoring it.
>
> ! Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup.
> l.21   \sortlist{nty}
>                  {nty}
> I've deleted a group-closing symbol because it seems to be
> spurious, as in `$x}$'. But perhaps the } is legitimate and
> you forgot something else, as in `\hbox{$x}'. In such cases
> the way to recover is to insert both the forgotten and the
> deleted material, e.g., by typing `I$}'.
>
> ! Undefined control sequence.
> \entry ...ata@\the \c@refsection @\blx@slist@name 
>                                              @\abx@field@entrykey 
> }\csu...
> l.22     \entry{__2004}{article}{}
>
> The control sequence at the end of the top line
> of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
> misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
> spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
> and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
>
> ! Undefined control sequence.
> <argument> ...equal \expandafter {\blx@slist@type
>                                               }{entry} {\listcsxadd {blx...
> l.33     \endentry
>
> The control sequence at the end of the top line
> of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
> misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
> spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
> and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
> ```

(This is the first time I ask a question, bear with me)

Would programming a new command make sense here? Stick with BibTeX but use a command making the "(Demmer, 2003: 165)" format into "(Demmer 2003: 165)". Is that possible?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: You need to make sure that you (or your editor) actually run Biber on your file and not still BibTeX. (Check out [Biblatex with Biber: Configuring my editor to avoid undefined citations](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864) for help with your editor.) If you change the backend it is a good idea to delete the temporary files (`.aux`, `.bcf`, `.bbl`) before recompiling from scratch. You need also to make sure that your versions of Biber and `biblatex` match (you can find a version matrix in the [`biblatex`docs](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf))

Comment: For further generic hints see [Troubleshooting for biber](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/286706/35864). You might also want to check out the contents of the `.blg` file (if you use Windows you might need to enable the option to show file extensions to find that file).